# Is there anything like VirtualEnv for Java?

Tags: java, python, virtualenv, jvm-languages

Is there anything similar to Python [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#virtualenv) for Java or JVM Languages?

Comment: Why are you asking this? (is there some other deeper problem?)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From what I understand, virtualenv enables you to have separate library installation paths, effectively separate "virtual" Python installations.

Java doesn't have the concept of a "system-wide installed" library<sup>(*)</sup>: It always searches the classpath for the libraries to be loaded. Since the classpath can be (and needs to be!) defined for each application, each application can pick-and-choose which libraries and which versions it wants to load.

If you go down one level deeper and have a single application that somehow needs two different versions of the same library at the same time, then you can do even that with some classpath trickery. It can get complicated, but it's definitely possible (OSGi is one example where this is supported, even Tomcat with two separate webapplications does this).

I've seens some references to security in the virtualenv description: Java has a pretty thorough security system built in. In server applications it's often turned off because it's just easier to configure this way, but you can easily configure what exactly a Java application is allowed to do.

<sup>(*) Almost, there are [extensions or extension libraries](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html), but they aren't used a lot and even those can easily be loaded from arbitrary directories.</sup>

Comment: This may be true for packages, but another thing python virtual environments help manage is versions of python itself. How do Java devs handle working on projects that use different versions of Java?

Comment: Script starting Java application that needs a specific installation of Java virtual machine, usually sets path to it in the JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: The Java install also depends on some system libraries.

Comment: Problem arises when some 3rd party inject its java version into path, so your java gets the wrong version. maven,gradle handles artifacts, and can force java version, but it just stops if the first java it finds has wrong version. currently the best solution seems to be using containers.

Answer (score 7):

Build tools like Ant, Maven, and gradle are the the closest thing to `pip` or `easy_install`.

The concept of virtualenv is done by the classpath. So there is no real need of virtualenv for Java

Answer (score 5):

Yes(see http://www.jenv.be/), like many other languages (Ruby, Python, Go, R, Php, etc. etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I know this may be a little late , but Groovy/Java has gvm http://gvmtool.net/ which is the Groovy version of Ruby's renv.

I would respectfully agree with Gautam K, luthur. Dependency and package version management for projects is not the  same as an isolated self-contained virtual environment to maintain different project.

My 2 cents
-W

Answer (score 3):

I have also been looking for a similar solution to simplify switching context between projects that use different Maven versions/settings and/or Java SDKs without having to modify `M2_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` settings every time.

To this end, I developed a solution that helps execute `mvn` commands with the appropriate configuration based on **per-project** settings (stored in a `.mvn` folder).

See: https://github.com/AlejandroRivera/maven-env

Be aware that this only helps if you're using Maven to build and/or run your project.

Comment: Why not to use [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by the assertion that "Java doesn't have the concept of a 'system-wide installed' library". What would you call the jar files in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib and $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext?

Regardless of whether or not Java "needs" a tool like virtualenv, it seems that something that allowed you to quickly switch between different Java environments (e.g. Java 6 with such-and-such security extensions, Java 7, etc.) would be handy - even if all it was actually doing under the covers was manipulating the PATH, JAVA_HOME, and CLASSPATH env variables.

Comment: I think this should have been a comment on my answer. I didn't see it before, so sorry for my late response: The `jre/lib/ext` holds extension libraries, which I've mentioned briefly in the footnote and they are indeed not used a lot. Yes, I agree there is some utility in quickly switching between JREs/JDKs and some such tools exist (for example Debian/Ubuntu has the alternatives system which allows you to switch the JDK used for the different java commands (among many other things)).

Answer (score 1):

Maven, you can explicitly specify which packages you would use in a java project

Comment: Maven is a build tool and has nothing in common with virtualenv ! Which is a totally different concept .

Comment: !!!!!!!!maven config file can specify which version and packages you would use in a specific java project, isn't it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: OP's question is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). He is asking how to map a Python solution to Java instead of asking how to solve a problem. The question should be "How do I manage dependencies in Java?" and the correct answer is to use Maven or one of it's competitors.

Comment: @jiggy you can't know what problem he is trying to solve (as he does not ask this). He could be 'just curious' as well

Answer (score 0):

Java as a language does not need the sandboxing features of virtualenv but a JVM Language like Jython can have VirtualEnv to use different environments without any conflict.

It is outlined in [this blog post](http://tech-nickel.blogspot.com/2009/07/running-pylons-with-jython-for.html)

Quote:

> Get virtualenv installed for Jython. Just type "jeasy_install
>   virtualenv". Once that finishes you should have a 'virtualenv' tool in
>   the Jython installation's bin folder.

So when using Jython different frameworks and packages can be used without any conflict with global packages.