# Why do we only talk about virtual environment in python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Why don't we talk about virtual environment in other programming language? Is there any equivalence for language like java, c++, javascript?

Is the concept in other language as important as in python? 
And I notice that the virtualenv was released initially in 2007. What did people use before that time? Or even before 2000?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300148/is-there-anything-like-virtualenv-for-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact we do talk about virtual environments in other languages. Here are some examples:

- Java: [Is there anything like VirtualEnv for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300148/is-there-anything-like-virtualenv-for-java)
- C++: [Is there an equivalent of python's virtualenv for C/C++ programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14685798/4518341)
- Javascript: [is there an virtual environment for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653495/4518341)
- Perl: [How can I install specialized environments for different Perl applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1423879/4518341)
- Ruby: [Ruby equivalent of virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/486995/4518341)
- Go: [Is there something like virtualenv for go? - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1p5ytc/stupid_noob_question_is_there_something_like/)
- Haskell: [Is there a notion of virtualenv in Haskell? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-notion-of-virtualenv-in-Haskell)